# Difference between int main() and signed main()

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, program-entry-point

What is difference between int main() and signed main().

```
signed main()
{
  ....
}

int main()
{
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 8):

`signed` by itself is the same thing as `int` so there is no difference as for how it compiles or works. But for a person reading the code it may be confusing since it’s not the general convention. It should just be `int` to reduce confusion.